# セルのUILabelの高さが変更できない

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

セルの高さが変わった時、そのセルの中にある`UILabel`の高さも変えようとしているのですが、どうやっても変更することができません。
セルの高さが変わる前の`UILabel`には3行分の文字が表示されており、それ以上は...で隠れています。そして、セルの高さが変わると同時に`UILabel`の全文を表示させようとしています。

```
detailText.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
detailText.numberOfLines = 0;
```

上記のコードを実行すると、`UILabel`の末尾にある...は消えるのですが、それ以上の文字が表示されません。なので、`UILabel`の高さを変更しようとしてみるのですが、変更することができません。
以下に現在のコードを記します。どうすればセルの`UILabel`の高さを変更することができるのでしょうか？どなたか分かる方がいればご教授いただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[tableView beginUpdates];

detailText.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
detailText.numberOfLines = 0;

CGRect cellHeight = detailText.frame;
cellHeight.size.height += 100;
detailText.frame = cellHeight;
[detailText setFrame:cellHeight];

[tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

---追記---
セルの高さの変更は以下のように行っています。

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (isButtonClicked) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            return 200;
        } else {
            return 100;
        }
    } else {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPathは問題なく実装されているのでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。heightForRowAtIndexPathに関するコードを追記いたしました。

Comment: @kojianuAutoLayoutが働いて、強制的にラベルのサイズが固定されているのかもしれません。

Comment: @Harawo ご回答ありがとうございます。「Use Auto Layout」のチェックを外すと、ラベルが全て表示されました！本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: @kojianu Use AutoLayoutのチェックを外す、というのは、その場逃れで、根本的な解決ではないので、これから、きちんとAutoLayoutを勉強なさることを、強くお勧めします。

Comment: @Harawo 了解しました。AutoLayoutについて調べてみます。